# Page table sizes

Tags: memory-management, operating-system, virtual

```
virtual address space 1GB
page size is 2KB. 
page table entry 2 bytes
```

using the above information how would I get the maximum size of of a single page table

This may have been asked before but the answers are vague or overly complex and offer no formula to follow. so I'm asking it in a way that will hopefully provide usable information.

I need to Know this for developing my file storage MM system. No code is need I just need to know the steps involved. These numbers are made up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Number of addressable pages = 1 GB / (2 KB/page) = 2^19 pages
- 2^19 pages × (2 bytes/page) = **1 megabyte**.

> page table entry requires 4 bytes

That contradicts the initial text block. You should probably program using abstract data structures, and let the total allocation sizes vary within the OS architecture.

Comment: Fixed I keep pasting my testing notes

Comment: Thank you that is works perfectly and is simple just what I was looking for.